# What's the typical algorithm that is follwed when installing a debian package with dpkg?

Tags: dpkg, debian

How things work when you install a debian package(s) with `dpkg`? I'd like to have an idea of how things are handled right after your fire in the command, like the unpackaging and especially the pre-/post-configurations for the pacakges specified. How do they manage incomplete configuration for cases when there are unmet dependencies? It would be really helpful if you add some details to the steps and/or point the the relevent sources. Thank you.

Comment: The answer is not simple at all. As a low level tool, dpkg halts if there are unmet depenencies. If a package can be installed, then the exact algorithm is detailed in [debian policy manual, chapter 6](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html#s-unpackphase)

Comment: Give a try to `strace` command.

Comment: @exore thanks for the [link](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html#s-unpackphase).. but still no idea if the _half-configured_ state of package holds other processes and how those half-configured are handled (like normal?)..

Answer (score 1):

> dpkg  is  a  tool to install, build, remove and manage Debian packages.
>          The primary and more user-friendly front-end for dpkg  is  aptitude.
>          dpkg  itself  is controlled entirely via command line parameters, which
>          consist of exactly one action and zero or  more  options.  The  action-
>          parameter tells dpkg what to do and options control the behavior of the
>          action in some way.

---

> -i, --install package-file...
>
> Install the package. If --recursive or -R option  is  specified,
>      package-file must refer to a directory instead.
>
> ### Installation consists of the following steps:
>
> 1. Extract the control files of the new package.
> 2. If  another version of the same package was installed before
>                the new installation, execute prerm script of the old package.
> 3. Run preinst script, if provided by the package.
> 4. Unpack the new files, and at the same time back  up  the  old
>                files, so that if something goes wrong, they can be restored.
> 5. If  another version of the same package was installed before
>                the new installation, execute  the  postrm  script  of  the  old
>                package.  Note  that  this  script is executed after the preinst
>                script of the new package, because new files are written at  the
>                same time old files are removed.
> 6. Configure   the   package.  See  --configure  for  detailed
>                information about how this is done.

---

> **-configure package**...|-a|**--pending**
>
> Configure  a  package  which  has  been  unpacked  but  not  yet
>                 configured.  If -a or --pending is given instead of package, all
>                 unpacked but unconfigured packages are configured.
>
> To reconfigure a package which has already been configured,  try
>                 the dpkg-reconfigure(8) command instead.
>
> **Configuring consists of the following steps:**
>
> 1. Unpack  the  conffiles, and at the same time back up the old
>                conffiles, so that they can be restored if something goes wrong.
> 2. Run postinst script, if provided by the package.

---

Also Visit:  [1](http://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg),[2](http://lists.debian.org/debian-dpkg/),[3](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dpkg),[4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manual_page_%28Unix%29),[5](http://www.hadrons.org/~guillem/debian/docs/origin.proposal) & [6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dselect).

***Refer PACKAGE STATUS, PACKAGE SELECTION STATUS & PACKAGE FLAGES From [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/dpkg.1.html).***

Comment: how does it manage the package configuration at hault due to unmet dependency?

Comment: @rusty please review the manual here: https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/index.html#contents You will find all your answers